# Hotkey for switching between desktops with maximized windows

Tags: desktop

I use ctrl- to switch between workspaces but if some application is maximized, it creates a new workspace between "Desktop 1" and "Desktop 2" so it's impossible to use a hotkey. Is it possible to switch to maximized window or assign a number?

Comment: When did macOS start inserting maximized applications between desktops rather than at the end?

Comment: @MarcWilson Yes, green button moves window to the end. But anyway, that workspace doesn't have a number nor a hotkey.

Comment: And of course I'm an idiot... macOS doesn't insert maximized applications anywhere, because they're just... maximized.  It inserts *full-screen* apps at the end if it's been told to do so.